# Show $|a|+|b|+|c|+|a+b+c| \geq  |a+b|+|b+c|+|c+a|$ for complex $a$, $b$, $c$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

How to prove for any complex numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, the inequality $$|a|+|b|+|c|+|a+b+c| \geq  |a+b|+|b+c|+|c+a|$$ is correct?

Comment: I changed the variables to $a$, $b$, and $c$ from $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$ so that the title would fit on one line on the front page, but if that's not acceptable to you you can change it back.

Comment: I feel there should be a $n$-variable version, like inclusion-exclusion formula: $$|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|-|a+b|-|a+c|-\dots-|c+d|+|a+b+c|+|b+c+d|+|c+d+a|+|d+a+b|-|a+b+c+d| \geq 0$$ but I'm unable to prove it.

Comment: Good generalization,I think MGNewman's method would be useful to proof that.

Comment: what a pity,the situation for n = 4 is wrong,let a=2,b=-1,c=-1,d=-1.

Comment: @sdcvvc There is a $n$-dimensional version: Prove exactly the same inequality, but when $a$, $b$ and $c$ are vectors in $\mathbf R^n$.

Comment: I have found some resources, future visitors might check this---[MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1004808/852512), [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/184671/169868) and [lastly this comprehensive analysis from springer](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00010-012-0178-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sides are non-negative, so it suffices to show that the square of the left-hand-side is at least the square of the right-hand-side. That is, we wish to show:
$$
|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|a+b+c|^2+2|ab|+2|bc|+2|ac+2(|a|+|b|+|c|)|a+b+c|
\geq\\
|a+b|^2+|b+c|^2+|a+c|^2+2(|a(a+b+c)+bc|+|b(a+b+c)+ac|+|c(a+b+c)+bc|)
$$
The square terms cancel:
$$
|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|a+b+c|^2 = 2|a|^2+2|b|^2+2|c|^2+2\operatorname{Re}(ab+bc+ac)=|a+b|^2+|b+c|^2+|a+c|^2
$$
and by the triangle inequality we have $|a(a+b+c)|+|bc|\geq |a(a+b+c)+bc|$ and cyclic permutations.