# Is Hlawkas Inequality holds for sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

im wondring is that inequality holds for any functionnal space such as sobolev space

and if it's true how we can write it in that space

[/HlawkasInequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HlawkasInequality.html)

any help would be apperciated

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment. Quote from [Hlawka's functional inequality](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00010-012-0178-2):

> Moreover, Witsenhausen showed that the space $L^p(0, 1)$ is a Hlawka space
> for $1\le p\le 2$. Therefore, one can see that all Banach spaces having the
> property that all its finite dimensional subspaces can be embedded linearly
> and isometrically in the space $L^p([0, 1])$, with some $1\le p\le 2$ are Hlawka
> spaces (see Niculescu and Persson and Lindenstrauss and Pelczy'nski).
> Further, Witsenhausen proved that a finite-dimensional real space with
> piecewise linear norm is embeddable in $L^1$ if and only if it is a Hlawka space.
> However, Neyman showed that in the general case embeddability in $L^1$
> does not characterize Hlawka spaces. Concluding, to the best of the author’s
> knowledge, no characterization of Hlawka spaces is presently known.

Comment: Could you answer this  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058105/pq-varphi-o-1-left-varphi-op-varphi-oq-right please

Comment: see my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004808/does-hlawka-inequality-follow-from-triangle-inequality/2487167#2487167